# When I assign a list to variable why Pycharm give me a prompt that is "this list creation could be rewritten as a list literal"?

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I am a Python beginner and have a puzzle.
When I write code like this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Pycharm give me a prompt that is "this list creation could be rewritten as a list literal".
But if it's replaced by

```
lst = list([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Pycharm doesn't say anything. Who could tell me why?

Is this code like `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]` legal in Python? Can I ignore prompt?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check your code to make sure you don't have `lst` somewhere else as `lst=[]`.

If you type the following:

```
lst= []
# more code
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You'll receive the prompt you got. You won't run into problems if you keep it that way but it's bad practice.

In those two cases you are using a function to change the variable: `list()` and `append()`. In the previous one where you're just redefining the variable explicitly.

Another improper example:

```
a = 7
# some code that has nothing to do with "a" or uses it
a = 8
```

Just set `a = 8` to begin with. No need to store `a = 7`.

Answer (score 45):

It's totally legal to write code like that in Python. However, writing code like

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12]
```

would be "better" than

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
... # code has nothing do to with lst
lst.append(12)
```

In general, the former one would have better performance than the latter one, but if the latter one is more readable in your case/you have a good reason doing that, then you can ignore the PyCharm prompt.

If it bothers you, you can turn this inspection off in

"PyCharm->settings->editor->inspection->Python->List creation could be..."