# Why does PyCharm rewrite `x.append(x[0])` to `x = [..., x[0]]`?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, when I make a list and then append the first item back onto the end:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list.append(my_list[0])
```

Pycharm underlines that first line of code and says:

```
"This list creation could be written as a list literal."
```

When I click on this suggestion to automatically fix the issue, it replaces the first line of code with:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', my_list[0]]
```

Which, of course, gets another error because `my_list` hasn't been defined yet. My question is, why does pycharm suggest this if it is clearly going to provide another error? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I assign a list to variable why Pycharm give me a prompt that is "this list creation could be rewritten as a list literal"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063384/when-i-assign-a-list-to-variable-why-pycharm-give-me-a-prompt-that-is-this-list)

Comment: Seems to be just a problem with how pycharm does the check.

Comment: Evidently the logic used doesn't cover the case where the thing you're appending comes from the list itself, it's just looking for the pattern `<thing> = [<stuff>]` `<thing>.append(<more>)` and converting it to `<thing> = [<stuff>, <more>]`.

Comment: Pycharm is trying to tell you that you could just write: `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`

Comment: @Tomerikoo but that's not the new version it actually gives you, and that *wouldn't* be equivalent in cases like e.g. `my_list = [[1, 2]]` `my_list.append(my_list[0])` (which it also tries to "fix").

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand why the example with a nested list is problematic, but why does the list with strings is not the same?

Comment: Because PyCharm doesn't chage the code to `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`, as the OP has included in the question it changes it to `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', my_list[0]]`, which breaks where `my_list` is not already defined and may break or give unexpected results in the cases where it is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh I was considering a manual change **based**  on the suggestion. I missed the part where Pycharm actually changes the code

Comment: In that case, is it something I should go further to report?

Comment: It looks like it was reported before, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26613.

Comment: I'm on the (oldish) 2019.3.2. Adding a line of ~something~ between lines does fix it for me also.

Comment: That issue is three years old, there's also an issue with that inspection around `.extend`: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16194 (worse, that creates code that runs with the *wrong behaviour*!) I'd guess these have been there as long as the feature has!

Comment: Jeez... It's amazing ^that^ issue has never been fixed! I mean it has been half a decade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like PyCharm is looking for situations like this:

```
<name> = [<values>]
<name>.append(<value>)
```

and offering to transform it to:

```
<name> = [<values>, <value>]
```

That's the limit of the logic for this inspection, so even though it will immediately report the unresolved reference if you choose to apply the suggested transformation, PyCharm will suggest it anyway.

It seems like any code (although *not* comments or empty lines) in-between will prevent the inspection from triggering, so e.g.

```
<name> = [<values>]
"shut up PyCharm"
<name>.append(<value>)
```

would suppress the inspection.

It seems that this bug [occurred previously](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26613) but has never been fixed; I'm still seeing it in PyCharm 2020.1.